# Pivot the result of two queries with UNION in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i am trying to get the pivot table of two queries result, from a MySql database

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 'NotSpot' as NotSpot,SUM(builds.Duration) as Duration , DATE_FORMAT(builds.date, "%Y-%c-%d") as date
FROM builds JOIN labels ON builds.Labels_label_id = labels.label_id
JOIN CITools ON CITools.tool_id=labels.CITools_tool_id
WHERE labels.label_name NOT LIKE '%SPOT%' AND CITools.tool_name='jenkins' AND builds.date AND builds.date >= '2022-03-01' AND builds.date <= '2022-03-10' 
GROUP BY DAY(date)

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Spot' as Spot,SUM(builds.Duration) as Duration , DATE_FORMAT(builds.date, "%Y-%c-%d") as date
FROM builds JOIN labels ON builds.Labels_label_id = labels.label_id
JOIN CITools ON CITools.tool_id=labels.CITools_tool_id
WHERE labels.label_name LIKE '%SPOT%' AND CITools.tool_name='jenkins' AND builds.date AND builds.date >= '2022-03-01' AND builds.date <= '2022-03-10' 
GROUP BY DAY(date)
) result
```

And this is the result :

```
__________________________________
NotSpot  |  Duration  |  date
________  __________   ______
NotSpot  1756343919   2022-03-01
NotSpot  1710800867   2022-03-02
NotSpot  1672806894   2022-03-03
NotSpot  859574350    2022-03-04
.         .            .
.         .            .
.         .            .
Spot      693071042     2022-03-01
Spot      728884095     2022-03-02
Spot      872995684     2022-03-03
.         .             .
.         .             .
.         .             .
__________________________________
```

And the result i want :

```
_______________________________________________
NotSpot Duration  |  Spot Duration  |  date     
__________________  ________________  _________
    1756343919       1756343919       2022-03-01
    1710800867       1672806894       2022-03-02
    1672806894       859574350        2022-03-03
    859574350        4267822656       2022-03-04
       .                 .                  .
       .                 .                  .
       .                 .                  .
________________________________________________
```

Could you help me please to get this result?
thank you in advance.

Comment: You need one `SELECT` only. Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but i need to get the two results in the same time, i think that 'case' will only give me the result of one case not the two cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `case` *expressions* to do *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT SUM(case when labels.label_name NOT LIKE '%SPOT%' then builds.Duration else 0 end) as notspot,
       SUM(case when labels.label_name LIKE '%SPOT%' then builds.Duration else 0 end) as spot, 
       DATE_FORMAT(builds.date, "%Y-%c-%d") as date
FROM builds JOIN labels ON builds.Labels_label_id = labels.label_id
JOIN CITools ON CITools.tool_id=labels.CITools_tool_id
WHERE CITools.tool_name='jenkins' AND builds.date AND builds.date >= '2022-03-01' AND builds.date <= '2022-03-10' 
GROUP BY DAY(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always imitate pivot using case function

```
select
    sum(case result.NotSpot when 'NotSpot' then result.Duration end) as NotSpot_Duration,
    sum(case result.NotSpot when 'Spot' then result.Duration end) as Spot_Duration,
    result.date
from result
group by result.date
```

Where "result" is exactly your query